# Force apps to not suspend, auto restart apps

Tags: ios, applications, multitasking

I have at least two apps which must run all the time in background, otherwise there is no point about it:

1. HID Mobile Access: Opens doors via Bluetooth LE, when phone is locked/in pocket
2. Noke: Opens my bike lock via Bluetooth LE, even when phone is locked/in pocket

I try hard to not kill these apps; I always leave them running and they are in the apps list when I double tap the home button.

However, both apps I mainly need twice a day (morning/evening) and in about 50% of the cases it just does not work. After minutes of desperation, I take the phone out, unlock, restart the apps and it works. That's absolutely unuseable!

Background data refresh etc is on for these apps. I think iOS puts them to suspend so they do not respond via Bluetooth LE even though I haven't killed them and they are in the apps list.

I can see similar behavior with MiniKeePass which I like to keep open so I have quick access to my passwords. But sometimes I still need to re-enter my (long) password although I haven't killed it.

Also, there must be a way for apps to keep running: Whatsapp, Threema but also ParcelTrack respond even when I killed them.

Comment: Whatsapp and ParcelTrack work because of notifications.

Answer (score 1):

When apps for a longer time have no activity iOS will freeze them down, unless they receive a notification to get 'active' again.

Comment: is absolutely correct.  It's up to the app developer to code the app correctly.  It's the responsibility of the **app** to notify iOS that it needs to be awake to function correctly.  It's **not** the responsibility of iOS to know when an app needs to woken-up to work.  You state you have Background Refresh turned on for the app so iOS is aware the app will need resources.  You should contact the app developers and let them know your issue.